# Max height in grid element won't wrok

Tags: css, css-grid

I have simple css/html where I'm trying to build nice onepage item selector, so you have items on your left inventory manager and when you click on them they will move them to another, but if you have more items than can div handle it should go in `overflow-y: scroll;` but it won't so I try add `max-height:100%;` so it won't destroy that nice look when there are not items but a parent don't have specific height number because it is in grid, I try use `calc(100vh - 4rem)` on parent so it would take 100vh without navbar but that doesn't looks good and it could make some problem in future when I will change navbar. You can copy that code into your html and remove all `div.item` so you will know how it should look like and then add `div.item` so you can see what is wrong

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "navbar" 
    "offer-manager";
}

.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: yellow;
}

.main {
  grid-area: offer-manager;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 8rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6rem 12rem;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "inventory controls offer" 
    "inventory controls ." 
    "inventory . .";
  background: green;
}

.inventory {
  grid-area: inventory;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
}

.selectedItems {
  grid-area: offer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <!-- navbar items -->
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inventory">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectedItems">

    </div>
    <div class="controlButtons">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit: I know that I could set fixed height but I need that size that I give to grid, so 100vh won't work because of navbar that is 4rem height.

edit2: calc(100vh - navbarHeight) kinda works but I would rather find something else because this would break after few changes in layout

Comment: For overflow to work you need a hard limit. That's why `calc(100vh - navbarHeight)` works. Without a fixed length, the content simply expands, and no overflow can occur. https://jsfiddle.net/aLvz72tb/

Comment: You are missing `overflow: auto` on `.container`.

Comment: @connexo but this will extend whole page, I just want overflow: scroll on .inventory and .selectedItems

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cleanest way to write it is that instead `auto` or `1fr` I use `calc(100vh - navbarHeight)` `grid-template-rows: 5rem calc(100vh - 5rem);`
So it would look like this:

```
.container {
        display: grid;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 5rem calc(100vh - 5rem);
        grid-template-areas: "navbar" "offer-manager";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Christian.P, I've just tried it out and placed a `max-height: 100vh;` on the inventory and it worked fine, the overflow scrolls as I think you intended.

As long as the height control isn't set to `max-height: 100%;` it should work. The 100% is relative to the `<div class="main>`'s height.

Comment: yea, but that's the problem, I don't want it to be 100vh because if you add few more item it would go 4rem downward because of navbar is 4rem long, I need height to be as it is without items

Comment: @user13424598 yes, I understand that but the point we were trying to make is that if you set the height to a specific value you won't encounter the problem you described above. We were only providing an example - one which you have accepted by using `calc(100vh - navbarHeight)`

Answer (score 0):

`1fr` means `minmax(auto,1fr)` whatever content you put in that row it will ask the grid to respect it's content size therefor there will be overflow if that content is taller.

```
.container { ... grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr; }
```

becomes

```
.container { ... grid-template-rows: 5rem minmax(0,1fr); }
```

Which says ignore my content place me where i should be then `overflow:auto` will kick in.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "navbar" "offer-manager";
}

.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: yellow;
}

.main {
  grid-area: offer-manager;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 8rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6rem 12rem;
  grid-template-areas: "inventory controls offer" "inventory controls ." "inventory . .";
  background: green;
}

.inventory {
  grid-area: inventory;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
}

.selectedItems {
  grid-area: offer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <!-- navbar items -->
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inventory">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectedItems"></div>
    <div class="controlButtons"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```